# Sitemap - where to start?

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I need to create a sitemap for my website to submit to search engines such as google. The site is dynamic so the sitemap links would be generated every time users add new content. The site is php based.   I don't know where to start.  Any help or resources out there?

Comment: You start with creating a list of links that are all leading to a page on your site. But only use one link for one page (not multiple links for the same page).

Comment: ok thanks ... I've been having a look.... basically it looks like that you query the database  and build  links for whatever type of pages you want the search engine to index.  So for each type of page i want indexed i create a link for it in the sitemap... right?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know your website but if you've got some CMS or so running, you might have already function to create links for pages. Also for the meta-information of those pages, like title, keywords, abstract, language, date etc.

Comment: I fail to understand how those automatic sitemap scripts work as each site is different and they will need to query different type of tables/database structure  to be able to build a link for each type of page?

Comment: Well instead of looking into the database, you can look into the website as well by just requestion and crawling it. You will get links as well then.

Comment: @harke - It's a niche classifieds site... so basically i build and append a link to the sitemap.xml file each time a user posts a new ad on the site.... What else can i put in a sitemap.xml?

Comment: You can put a lot in there, look into the specification what's all possible: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: So which one's better then automatic scripts that create a sitemap by crawling or my own that generates a sitemap through database?

Comment: @hakre - Put all those comments as an answer and i'll select it as an accepted solution

Comment: I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8907514/367456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with creating a list of links that are all leading to a page on your site. But only use one link for one page (not multiple links for the same page).

Next to the link you can put a lot in there, look into the [XML sitemap specification](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.html) what is all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cronjob to build your sitemap at the end of each day.  The cronjob script can access your pages or post table and check maybe for site_map status.

```
`site_map` tinyint(1) unsigned not null default '0'
```

Grab all the pages/posts where site_map === 0 then append those links to your sitemap.xml file.  Once built set site_map to 1 and ping the search engines.

it is adviced to do this at the end of each working day and not each time a new post/page is created , anytime after 00:00:00 should be fine.

**Edit: you might also want to check for canonical links, ie: duplicate content**